# commons configuration: comma and multikey issue

Tags: java, apache-commons

My requirement was to update a key/value pair property file for which Commons Configuration is used.

But problem is when you save any text using this api it remove space after comma in a value.
If you disable parsing then it create multiple keys of safe name broken by comma :(

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("prop.properties");
            //config.setDelimiterParsingDisabled(true);
            config.save();
```

Expected value (with no truncation of spaces after before comma): 
Name = some ,       Text  ,  for testing

If setDelimiterParsingDisabled is false then below is outout all spaces gone

> Name = some,Text,for testing

If that is True then below is output

```
Name = some 
Name = Text 
Name = for testing
```

I need first one with all space intact means key as is...how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both things cannot be achieved so what is id is I changed Delimeter to carrot ^ sign and not it behaving as I like.

So this is answered.